# Quaternions product with or without minimum rotation arc

Tags: rotation, quaternions

Two questions about quaternion product.

1. The product of two or more quaternions, all having a minimum rotation arc, produces a quaternion with a minimum rotation arc?
2. The product of two or more quaternions, if at least one quaternion does not have a minimum rotation arc, produces a quaternion without minimum rotation arc?

Comment: What do you mean by "minimum rotation arc"? There is the eigen-axis of the quaternion and an angle associated with the rotation. Is that what you mean?

Comment: There are infinite rotations on the unit sphere moving a point A to another point B, but only one rotation has minimum arc, the shortest path on the unit sphere from A to B. This rotation has axis R = AO x BO (cross product of vectors from sphere center O to each point).